# Apache forward everything to Tomcat except webmail

Tags: apache, tomcat, forward, webmail, ajp

I have my Apache HTTP server set up to forward all requests to Tomcat, i.e. proxy_ajp.conf looks like:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

where Tomcat is listening on port 8009.  This works find except when I try to access squirrelmail (i.e. webmail) on the server.  Is there a way to forward all requests to Tomcat **except** those going to /webmail/?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really more of a serverfault sort of a question, but yes, you can do it.

You need to use a RewriteRule, something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond REQUEST_URI !^/webmail.*
RewriteRule / /tomcat/

<Location /tomcat>
     ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8099/
</Location>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when restarting apache that says ProxyPass can't have a path when defined in a location.  Any work around?

Comment: See the edited version. There is only 1 param to proxypass when it's in a location.

Comment: Thanks.  That helped.  It looks like the rewrite rule isn't working though.  I can go to /webmail and see the squirrelmail page, but I can't go to my Tomcat app unless I explicitly type /tomcat/.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I probably screwed up the syntax a bit. Turn on rewrite logging and see what it says. Try adding a "." before the * after webmail, too.

Comment: Another solution is to add this: "ProxyPass /webmail !" before the original ProxyPass.